# Aggregate Excel rows based on a field - concatenating values

Tags: excel, concatenation, aggregate

I have a table (Excel Worksheet) with a list of contracts with some details. One contract can have several products or several comments added, which will cause ContractID duplication.
How can I aggregate (concatenate the Products and Comments) so I can guarantee that a second worksheet shows one line per contract?

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ ContractID ║ Value ║ Paid ║ Product  ║ Customer ║ CustomerFeedback ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╣
║       1000 ║   100 ║  100 ║ Product1 ║ John     ║ Thank you!       ║
║       1001 ║   120 ║    0 ║ Product1 ║ Anna     ║ Cheers!          ║
║       1001 ║   120 ║    0 ║ Product2 ║ Anna     ║ Cheers!          ║
║       1002 ║    90 ║   90 ║ Product4 ║ Richard  ║ Baaah!           ║
║       1002 ║    90 ║   90 ║ Product4 ║ Richard  ║ New Feedback!    ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

So we would only have 3 rows. Contract 1001 would have the product as: "Product1, Product2" and contract 1002 would have the comment as: "Baaah!, New Feedback!"

Comment: Wouldn't a pivot table work?

Comment: What have you tried?  This kind of problem has been asked and answered before in SO.  What was wrong with any of those solutions?  Please show examples of your code, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Dont have code. This is a MSExcel question. I couldn't find any similar questions. And believe me, I did search.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet, because dont even know where to start. How would a pivot work on this? How would you set it up (rows, cols, values) ?

Comment: The easy answers use VBA. Is that an option?